# Check whether deployed in cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-run

I have a python program running in a Docker container. My authentication method depends on whether the container is deployed in GCP or not. Ideally I'd have a function like this:

```py
def deployment_environment():
    # return 'local' if [some test] else 'cloud'
    pass
```

What's the most idiomatic way of checking this? My instinct is to use env named `[APP_NAME]_DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT` which gets set either way -- but making sure this is set correctly has too many moving parts. Is there a GCP package/tool which can check for me?

Comment: Which Google Cloud service are you deploying on? That makes a difference in which methods are available.

Comment: Cloud Run, specifically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions I've arrived at:

#### With env

Set an [env var](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var) when deploying, like so:

```sh
gcloud functions deploy [function-name] --set-env-vars ENV_GCP=1
```

Then, in your code:

```py
import socket


def deployment_environment():
    return 'cloud' if ('ENV_GCP' in os.environ) else 'local'
```

| Pros | Cons |
| --- | --- |
| intent is clear, both setting and using env | more involved |
| idiomatic | relies on user setting env correctly |

#### Via Python, with Sockets

```py
import socket


def deployment_environment():
    try:
        socket.getaddrinfo('metadata.google.internal', 80)
        return 'cloud'
    except socket.gaierror:
        return 'local'
```

| Pros | Cons |
| --- | --- |
| more succinct | makes improper use of `try/catch` |
| doesn't rely on an extra step of setting env | dependency on socket package & GCP runtime contract |